# How to implement multiple templates of home page together in ASP.NET MVC c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have 4 different templates of a home page[ with different data's from the database]. I would like change periodically from one to another from some sort of back-end admin access. I have created 4 index(index1.aspx,index2.aspx..) pages. what would be the easiest way to change the default index page from time to time.

I imagine doing that by creating a config file and modifying that.. is there any better way of doing that?

Comment: What does better mean to you? This is also very business driven.  Who is changing this template?  Do you have access to your production machines?

Comment: Better means most cost effective way. an example of this would be- changing wordpress themes.. simply select one of the templates and press activate-that's all!

Comment: Cost effective how?  For the actual change? So if I gave you a solution that took 100 hours to implement but you could change themes in 5 seconds you'd be ok with that? -- Sorry if I'm being a bother.  These type of questions come up a lot and its always better if the person replaces "best" with "most cost effective to implement".

Comment: so, what are the implementation suggestions for either way - best or cost effective..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate file for storing appsettings.  Add a setting for your current home page.

Store this setting in external config file.

```
  <appSettings file="appSettings.config">
     Your other settings
  </appSettings>
```

And your appSettings.config

```
  <appSettings>
     <add key="currentHomePage" value="HomePage1"/>
  </appSettings>
```

You can programatically modify these settings, which you would do for your admin users.

[Here is a link that shows how to do this](http://odetocode.com/Articles/418.aspx)

Now in your controller action, you can simply retrieve the current home page from the app settings.

string currentHomePage = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["currentHomePage"];

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a controller action like:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    return View();  // Implies Index.aspx
}
```

You probably just want to swap out views:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    HomePageType homePageType = GetHomePageTypeFromDb();
    HomePageModel model = new HomePageModel();

    switch (homePageType) 
    {
        case Type1: return View("Index1", model);
        case Type2: return View("Index2", model);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i dont want to store the homepage types in db. what would you suggest?

Comment: @Emon, oh, I misunderstood your original question.  By my method `GetHomePageTypeFromDb` is just an example.  I'm assuming it's just returning an enum value.  How would you like it to work?  If no the db, then where?  Do you want a random home page returned?

Comment: no- not random. let me try to explain it a bit more. i have only 4 templates and its not going to change. so saving these templates model in db will result 4 rows in a table. so I was thinking to make some kind of config file or xml that will hold these layouts as well as have one as a default one. I also would like to give an access to the admin to change the default page with a different one out of 4. obviously in that case by modifying the config or xml file. --so this is just my thought. though I dont know how to set a default page or controller action in xml and access them..:(

Comment: please suggest  me if you know how?. And also is that sounds the right approach to solve the described scenario to you?? if not what is the right one?